# How do I specify if the shipment is Residential in UPS API?

Tags: php, web-services, api, ups

I'm using **UPS api**(JSON) refer from the ups.com developer kit.

1)I need shipment rating list with "Residential Shipment".
2)I need Add shipment with "Residential Address".

I am add `ResidentialAddressIndicator` as 1 in `ShipTo` address.(I am refer from UPS doc.)
But it's failed.

2)Sample code:

```
...........
...........
 "ShipTo": {
    "Name": "Ship To Name",
    "AttentionName": "Ship To Attn Name",
    "Phone": {
      "Number": "1234567890"
    },
    "Address": {
      "AddressLine": "195 N main st",
      "City": "Sebastopol",
      "StateProvinceCode": "CA",
      "PostalCode": "95472",
      "CountryCode": "US",
      "ResidentialAddressIndicator":"1" //I am refer from UPS doc.        
    }       
  },
..........
..........
```

Your answers are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the <ShipTo> element add <Residential Address/>, you can find this in the Shipping Package XML Developers Guide that UPS provides.