# Indicate residential address with UPS Rate API

Tags: xml, api, ups

How do I indicate that a shipment is to a residential address with the UPS Rate API? I'd like to get the same price as with the UPS website calculator https://wwwapps.ups.com/ctc

I've tried both:

```
<ns2:ResidentialAddressIndicator></ns2:ResidentialAddressIndicator>
```

and

```
 <ResidentialAddressIndicator></ResidentialAddressIndicator>
```

and tried both of those as both a sibling and a child to

```
<ns2:ShipTo>
```

This is from the "Rating Package - Web Services Developers Guide.pdf" that I downloaded with the API. (Their downloaded sample XML request was outdated and I had to write to support and get a new sample XML request file. So maybe other things are outdated, as well?)

The response always matches the commercial price, as seen on the UPS website. I think that I have the other settings correct since the price does match the website's commercial price (it's not something completely different).

Note that this answer [How do I specify if the shipment is Residential in UPS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529352/how-do-i-specify-if-the-shipment-is-commercial-or-residential-in-ups-api) is 5 years old and ow gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag needed to go down one more level and be nested within the address tag:

```
<ns2:Address>
   ...
   <ns2:ResidentialAddressIndicator></ns2:ResidentialAddressIndicator>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing in a full address (as you should be for accurate rating) the UPS Rating API will automatically re-rate a shipment regardless of the residential indicator value. You will get a warning response back along with the rates that states it was re-classified.